# Windows Function for Query Block - Count and Sum

Tags: database, oracle

How can i rewrite the below query to utilize the Window Function?

```
select bm.book_cd_id, count(*), sum(amt) 
from   ldfods_prd.gl_fincl_dtl fd, 
       ldfods_prd.gl_book_cd_hier_mstr bm
where  fd.book_cd_mstr_id = bm.book_cd_mstr_id
and    fy = 2017 
and    acctg_prd = 1
group by bm.book_cd_id;
```

Comment: The analytic functions are those with a  windowing clause so it depends on what you want the results to show. If you can show some expected results that might be a starting point.

Comment: Windowing clauses apply to analytic functions. Right now your query uses aggregating functions. You're talking about changing the query to produce a different result set. So you need to define the different result you need.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question would be this:

```
select DISTINCT bm.book_cd_id, 
       count(*) over ( partition by bm.book_cd_id), 
       sum(amt) over ( partition by bm.book_cd_id)
from   ldfods_prd.gl_fincl_dtl fd, 
       ldfods_prd.gl_book_cd_hier_mstr bm
where  fd.book_cd_mstr_id = bm.book_cd_mstr_id
and    fy = 2017 
and    acctg_prd = 1;
```

But that'd actually be a step in the wrong direction.  Your posted query is basically "give me one record in my result set for each `book_cd_id` and, for each, give me number of records having that `book_cd_id` and the sum of those records' `amt` columns."  The way you wrote your query, using regular aggregate functions, is exactly how to do that.  You wouldn't want to introduce windowing functions just for the heck of it.

Comment: I am thinking - if there is a way to rewrite this one with a co-related subquery and link both the block and get the same set of results. Since group by clause lead to sort/merge - i was thinking window sort over sort/merge may execute quicker.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be faster.  The `DISTINCT` keyword is effectively grouping by all the columns in the result set.  Windowing functions are great and solve many problems, but they're not a golden hammer.  Your original query is simple and fast.